# Listview header formatting does not format buttons

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, header

In a listview a header with two buttons is added. You can see the buttons "none" and "all" below right under the actionbar. Then follows the first item of the list. The buttons should be in the centered and take equal space.

[image]

I have a similar solution for a footer (snapshot from a different listview) where it works. You can see the bottom of the list and then the two buttons nicely distributed horizontally.

[image]

Here is the code from the header:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_none"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16"
    android:layout_marginRight="16"
    android:text="@string/btn_none" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_all"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16"
    android:layout_marginRight="16"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="@string/btn_all" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried Relative Layout but again it works only in the footer and not in the header. How can I adjust the buttons in the header?

Here is the footer code. It contains an additional view to establish a horizontal line.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dts_id_button_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dts_btn_cancel"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/btn_cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dts_btn_done"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/btn_done" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Removing the style leads to the same placement of the buttons - only now they have the grey windows button style.

Comment: `I have a similar solution for a footer (snapshot from a different listview) where it works` post the footer too, so that we can spot out the differences

Comment: I just added the code. There is a horizontal line above the buttons that I don't need. However, I just tested it with this line and now the buttons are the way I need them. After taking the divider out it looks just right. It seems it needs a "dummy" parent for the horizontal distribution to work. Thanks for the tip.